# Proper indentation for using scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s) statement to get string

Tags: c, string, types, printf, user-input

I use `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s)` statement to get string, but what is the proper indentation to print this string?

I am a beginner and overall confused with string input-output instructions. Some tips on this topic would be helpful...!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and how to [edit] your question to show it (and to put the actual question inside the question body, and edit the title to be a short summary).

Comment: The way you print a string is independent of the way you get it from user. Use something like `printf("%s\n", s);` to print the string and the a new line.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper" identation? You can print it anyway you like

Comment: Please don't take this as an insult, but if you are a beginner, string input in C is always going to be a little bit confusing.  Please don't even try to use `%[^\n]` or `%*c`.  They're not worth it, and no one should have suggested them to you.  Please just use `%s` at first.  It's not perfect, but when you're ready to learn about its shortcomings and move on to something better, the "something better" to move on to is [`fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537), not anything involving fancy `scanf` format strings..

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you have achieved yourself. Then desribe what is unsatisfying about the result you get. Also, have a look at http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html I do not really want to contradict Steve Summit, but please understand that using `"%s"` is dangerous in the presence of bad luck or malicious users.

Comment: Prathamesh Kakde: "what is the proper indentation to print this string?" --> Try `printf("%s", s);`